# JSQMessagesViewController and GeoFire can´t work together?

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller, geofire

I'm working on an app on **Xcode** with **Swift 3**. I'm Using **GeoFire** to get the users location and I want to add on a messages feature, the thing is that when I try to install the **JSQMessagesViewController** pod on my project, it shows up an error with **GeoFire**

```
    "FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h" not found.
```

It happened when I installed the **JSQMessagesViewController** pod without doing something else in my project.
¿Why is that? ¿How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is not because of JSQMessagesViewController. GeoFire just requires FirebaseDatabase framework. Find the **FirebaseDatabase.framework** file in the pods project then in the file inspector on the right look for **Target Membership** section then check **GeoFire**. Try to rebuild. You must do this every time you update or install new pods.

Answer (score 1):

I would just delete your derived data and try to build again.